# Vim Regexes to match classes, methods or functions

Tags: python, regex, vim

I am currently developing/updating a VIM plugin that uses a lot of VIM Regexes to match a class/method/function in **Python**

My starting point was to re-use what I could find, in this case this is what I have been using:

Matches a Class

```
    "^\\s.*class\\s\\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\\+"
    "\ . "\\s*\\((\\([a-zA-Z0-9_,. \\t\\n]\\)*)\\)\\=\\s*:"
```

Matches a Method

```
    "^\\s*.def\\s\\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\\+\\s*(\\s*self\\_[^:#]*)\\s*:"
```

Matches a Function

```
    "^\\s*def\\s\\+[a-zA-Z0-9_]\\+\\s*(\\_[^:#]*)\\s*:"
```

However, the above proves way to strict and doesn't match in certain situations (e.g. if you start a method and continue in a new line after "(").

So after much debating, I decided to relax my RegExes and this is what I am currently using:

Class:

```
'\v^(.*class )'
```

Method:

```
'\v^(.*def)&(.*self)'
```

Function:

```
 '\v^(.*def )&(.*self)@!'
```

So far so good, but I think I lost the balance of the regexes: it is way to lenient now.

The question would be:

> "Could you ad a bit of RegEx expertise to my lenient regexes so that they match a bit better but don't become overly strict?"

**Bonus Points** if you keep the *very magic* flags in your answer!

Comment: class/method/function in what language(s)?

Comment: 'Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.' (Jamie Zawinski).  Are you really sure this is what you want to do?  The syntax of C/Java/C++/whatever you're using isn't ideally suited to regular expression matching.  What is this for?  We might be able to suggest some alternative approaches.

Comment: Ooops! sorry, I edited the question so it reflects the language (Python). Thanks for noting!

Comment: Let's face it, the only reliable way is to build (at the very least) a tokenizer - which is more than a bunch of huge regexes (even though regexes are an important part).

Comment: Well, the current approach works, but I am looking for something a bit more strict - that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might help, i'm not a python nor VIM expert.

`\v^\s*def\s+(\w+)\s*\(\s*(self[^)]*)\)\s*:`

```
\v           # very magic
^            # start of line
   \s*       # 0 or more whitespace
   def       # 'def'
   \s+       # 1 or more whitespace
   (         # start capture group 1
      \w+       # 1 or more word [a-zA-Z0-9_] chars
   )         # end capture group 1
   \s*       # 0 or more whitespace
   \(        # '(' literal open parenthesis
   \s*       # 0 or more whitespace
   (         # start capture group 2
      self   # 'self'
      [^)]*     # 0 or more of not ')', includes newline
   )         # end capture group 2
   \)        # ')' literal close parenthesis
   \s*       # 0 or more whitespace
   :         # ':'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to tackle the question and explain, step by step, every single part of the regex. Although you did not "fixed" my regex, you gave me enough weaponry to polish it myself. Thanks!

Comment: @alfredodeza, no problem. I think you can add \v  (\v^\s*...) and it should work. The [^)] normally include newlines as does \s. In PCRE style if you just want whitespace without newline it would be [^\S\n]. I haven't found info on char classes for vim regex though. Good luck!